# How to access istio created dashboard

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, portforwarding, istio

I installed *istio* on *kubernetes* without helm.

I can see pods and services are created in istio-system namespace.

All service like grafana, Prometheus are created and their ports are not exposed.

As load-balancer-service is created so that one load balancer is also created in AWS, I wanted to access grafana, prometheus etc dashboard from an external network through newly created load balancer endpoint  but that dashboard is not accessible from load balancer endpoint.

I tried port forwarding recommended by istio docs:

```
kubectl -n istio-system port-forward $(kubectl -n istio-system get pod -l app=grafana -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') 3000:3000 &
```

These is working with only http://localhost:3000 but not accessible with http://publicip:3000

```
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                              PORT(S)                                                                                                                                      AGE
grafana                  ClusterIP      172.20.192.71    <none>                                                                   3000/TCP                                                                                                                                     1m
istio-citadel            ClusterIP      172.20.111.103   <none>                                                                   8060/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                                           1m
istio-egressgateway      ClusterIP      172.20.123.112   <none>                                                                   80/TCP,443/TCP,15443/TCP                                                                                                                     1m
istio-galley             ClusterIP      172.20.45.229    <none>                                                                   443/TCP,15014/TCP,9901/TCP                                                                                                                   1m
istio-ingressgateway     LoadBalancer   172.20.94.157    xxxx-yyyy.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com   15020:31336/TCP,80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15029:32146/TCP,15030:30126/TCP,15031:31506/TCP,15032:30501/TCP,15443:31053/TCP   1m
istio-pilot              ClusterIP      172.20.27.87     <none>                                                                   15010/TCP,15011/TCP,8080/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                       1m
istio-policy             ClusterIP      172.20.222.108   <none>                                                                   9091/TCP,15004/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                                 1m
istio-sidecar-injector   ClusterIP      172.20.240.198   <none>                                                                   443/TCP                                                                                                                                      1m
istio-telemetry          ClusterIP      172.20.157.227   <none>                                                                   9091/TCP,15004/TCP,15014/TCP,42422/TCP                                                                                                       1m
jaeger-agent             ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                   5775/UDP,6831/UDP,6832/UDP                                                                                                                   1m
jaeger-collector         ClusterIP      172.20.92.248    <none>                                                                   14267/TCP,14268/TCP                                                                                                                          1m
jaeger-query             ClusterIP      172.20.168.197   <none>                                                                   16686/TCP                                                                                                                                    1m
kiali                    ClusterIP      172.20.236.20    <none>                                                                   20001/TCP                                                                                                                                    1m
prometheus               ClusterIP      172.20.21.205    <none>                                                                   9090/TCP                                                                                                                                     1m
tracing                  ClusterIP      172.20.231.66    <none>                                                                   80/TCP                                                                                                                                       1m
zipkin                   ClusterIP      172.20.200.32    <none>                                                                   9411/TCP                                                                                                                                     1m
```

As shown in above I'm trying to access grafana dashboard using load balncer as well as port forwarding but I haven't get grafana dashboard

Comment: What do you mean by "installing without helm" ?

Comment: there are two ways to install istio on kubernetes one is without helm and another with helm.

Helm is a tool that streamlines installing and managing Kubernetes applications. Think of it like apt/yum/homebrew for Kubernetes

Comment: I know what helm is, But installing istio without helm is not recommended anymore, and even not really documented for 1.1 version. Anyway I don't think this will change anything. What do you get when you do a `curl -v xxxx-yyyy.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create [Istio Gateway and VirtualService](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#configuring-ingress-using-an-istio-gateway) in order to forward your requests to `grafana` service running by default on port 3000

Firstly, let's check `grafana` and `istio-ingressgateway` service

```
kubectl get svc grafana istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)                                                                                                                                      AGE
grafana                ClusterIP      100.71.67.105   <none>                                                                    3000/TCP                                                                                                                                     18h
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   100.64.42.106   <Public IP address>   15020:31766/TCP,80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15029:32576/TCP,15030:30728/TCP,15031:31037/TCP,15032:31613/TCP,15443:32501/TCP   18h
```

So, we have `grafana` running service listening on port 3000, and default `istio-ingressgateway` LoadBalancer service running with assigned public ip address.

Then we create `gateway` to use this default LoadBalancer.

```
$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: grafana-gateway
  namespace: istio-system # Use same namespace with backend service
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: HTTP
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
EOF
```

Then configure route to `grafana service` for traffic entering via the this gateway:

```
$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grafana
  namespace: istio-system # Use same namespace with backend service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - grafana-gateway # define gateway name
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 3000 # Backend service port
        host: grafana # Backend service name
EOF
```

Then hit the `http://<public_ip_istio_ingressgateway>`, you should see the grafana dashboard

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: do you have any idea if I forwarded grafana on 3000 port and I want to access it with public IP of that host? (if few dashboards I don't want to expose on the internet all time )

Answer (score -1):

```
kubectl -n istio-system  port-forward svc/kiali 20001
```

Then hit `http://localhost:20001/kiali/`

Comment: but that localhost is Linux VM. to access dashboard I assigned public IP for that VM and tried to access it over the internet but it is not working

Comment: what if I wanted to access 20001 port using public IP instead of localhost