# How to access grafana-istio dashboard using ip address?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, grafana, minikube, istio

I am using `minikube` to run kubernetes cluster. I followed the setup given in [Istio Docs](https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/) to install istio plugin. I am able to access the dashboard using `localhost:3000` but unable to access using `ip:3000`.

Checked firewall. It isn’t blocking any port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make grafana service type `NodePort` for this. You can change it with `$ kubectl edit svc grafana -n istio-system` and change `.spec.type` from `ClusterIP` to `NodePort` then save and quit editor.

To access grafana `$ kubectl get svc grafana -n istio-system` and get `NodePort` field then access it via `ip:$NodePortValue`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you are using `istio` it's not so easy to just change service type. You have to configure Istio `VirtualService` and create `Gateway`.

I am posting this answer as community wiki related to another stack case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56019381/11148139
As mentioned question have 1 downvote and might be delete in the future I am posting for future use in this case.

============================================

You can create [Istio Gateway and VirtualService](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#configuring-ingress-using-an-istio-gateway) in order to forward your requests to `grafana` service running by default on port 3000

Firstly, let's check `grafana` and `istio-ingressgateway` service

```
kubectl get svc grafana istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)                                                                                                                                      AGE
grafana                ClusterIP      100.71.67.105   <none>                                                                    3000/TCP                                                                                                                                     18h
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   100.64.42.106   <Public IP address>   15020:31766/TCP,80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15029:32576/TCP,15030:30728/TCP,15031:31037/TCP,15032:31613/TCP,15443:32501/TCP   18h
```

So, we have `grafana` running service listening on port 3000, and default `istio-ingressgateway` LoadBalancer service running with assigned public ip address.

Then we create `gateway` to use this default LoadBalancer.

```
$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: grafana-gateway
  namespace: istio-system # Use same namespace with backend service
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: HTTP
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
EOF
```

Then configure route to `grafana service` for traffic entering via the this gateway:

```
$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grafana
  namespace: istio-system # Use same namespace with backend service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - grafana-gateway # define gateway name
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 3000 # Backend service port
        host: grafana # Backend service name
EOF
```

Then hit the `http://<public_ip_istio_ingressgateway>`, you should see the grafana dashboard

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the grafana service type.

You can use `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` as the service type.

Use `NodePort` with ip or you can simply use the IP address of `LoadBalancer` to access the service online of grafana vai internet.